# cordova-plugin-dialogs:navigator.notification.prompt not working properly

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

```js
 function onPrompt(results) {
   if (results.buttonIndex == 1) {
     alert('sucess');//working
   } else {
     alert('fail');//not working
   }
 }

navigator.notification.prompt(
  'Please enter your name',
  onPrompt,
  'Registration',
  ['Ok', 'Exit'],
  'Maruthi'
);
```

onprompt() else part is not working when user press exit but if is correctly working as its expected when user press on ok button.

Comment: alert(results.buttonIndex);... alert the button getindex and check...

Comment: I've tested your code and it's working fine on android and iOS. In which platform are you testing? are you sure you are using an updated plugin?

Comment: i am testing it in Windows platform (OS windows Mobile 10). its working fine now. I had different problem with my logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the type of buttonIndex:

```
function onPrompt(results) {
   if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {
     alert('sucess');
   } else {
     alert('fail');
   }
 }
```

If you use only two equal signs, the 1 means TRUE, which is always TRUE in your function, because buttonIndex has a value.

Comment: Hi, Joerg. Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried with === too but no use :(

Answer (score 1):

This plugin return different **buttonIndex** for different platforms, because in some platforms this alert also has close button "x" which also is counting, you should also check and platform. If I remember this issue is on iOS  where 1-close button; 2 -ok and 3 -exit